# Fatal error: Call to undefined function media_filter

Tags: 7, media, upgrading

I've upgraded Media module from 2.0-alpha2+6-dev and 2.0-beta1, however now I've the following error on some random pages:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function `media_filter()` in my_module.module on line 224

My code in `hook_field_formatter_view` in my module is:

```
$element[0]['#markup']
  = '<div class="my-formatter-slide-down-container"><div class="text-summary ' . ($settings['hide_summary'] ? 'hiding' : '') . '">'
  . media_filter($text_summary)
  . '<a href="' . $read_more_link . '" class="read-more">' . $read_more_text . '</a>'
  . '</div></div>';
```

The code of that [`media_filter` function](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!media!includes!media.filter.inc/function/media_filter/7) was:

```
function media_filter($text) {
  $text = preg_replace_callback(MEDIA_TOKEN_REGEX, 'media_token_to_markup', $text);
  return $text;
}
```

What is the current replacement for that function which I can use instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prior to newer version of Media, `media_wysiwyg_filter` should be used instead which will perform media markup filter. This can be found in `modules/media_wysiwyg/includes/media_wysiwyg.filter.inc`.

The code is:

```
/**
 * Filter callback for media markup filter.
 */
function media_wysiwyg_filter($text) {
  $text = preg_replace_callback(MEDIA_WYSIWYG_TOKEN_REGEX, 'media_wysiwyg_token_to_markup', $text);
  return $text;
}
```